# Grub screen remains at "Minimal BASH like line editing is supported" after installing Ubuntu on Surface Pro 4

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi, surface

I know there are a bunch of questions similar to mine, but I don't know what went wrong and how to fix it :(

Now, some back story.
I have managed once to install Ubuntu with my Surface Pro 4 on an micro SSD card a few months ago as a test. After the test was successful, and after a few months, I bought a proper SSD card to properly use it.

But now grub doesn't work any more.

The checklist:

- Disabled secure boot
- Make sure that the EFI files are in the first partition of the /dev/nvme* drives, not on /dev/sda
- Then tried to use boot repair which seemed only to understand the /dev/sd* partitions ([log here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/K8Fnng8sWV/)).
- Attempt to reinstall Ubuntu tells me clearly that the partition already has Ubuntu there.
- Formatting the dist and reinstalling Ubuntu, still no luck
- Trying 18.04 and 19.10 and again still no luck

I don't know what to try next...

Comment: Boot-Repair does not show NVMe drives in first part of report. It uses bootinfoscript for that. https://github.com/arvidjaar/bootinfoscript/issues/5  It looked like originally grub was in ESP on NVMe drive, but now is on ESP in sda1. Is Windows bitlocker on or fast start up on? Then partitions will not be shown and grub will not boot Windows.http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @oldfred Indeed the original is (and should probably be) in NVMe drive. The problem is not booting Windows, the problem is that there's not selection at all to boot either linux or windows or anything.

Comment: If you press Escape right after UEFI/BIOS screen does grub menu show? It shows 10 sec default. And with two boot entries should show by default. Do both systems boot when you use the UEFI boot menu directly?

Comment: There's a grub command prompt, but no grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue like this:

- reinstalling/clean installing ubuntu just to be on the safe side
- boot into windows (linux still doesn't boot due to grub issues)
- install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) following the [official instructions](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows)
- reboot, and not only it works, but as a bonus I have a nive graphical UI to select operating systems